# How to make Material Ui GridList Responsive to small screen in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

How do I make Material-UI GridList responsive on mobile? Everything is working fine on a big screen but when I go to mobile it does not respond to one Column. I know that I am doing something wrong but I don't know exactly what it is. I will appreciate some explanations why the code is not working, so that I can understand React and material-Ui very well, and also solution on how to get it to work. I started learning React a few weeks ago and material-ui less than a week now.

This is my Component.

```
import React from "react";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

import GridList from "@material-ui/core/GridList";
import GridListTile from "@material-ui/core/GridListTile";
import GridListTileBar from "@material-ui/core/GridListTileBar";
import ListSubheader from "@material-ui/core/ListSubheader";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";

const useStyles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    overflow: "hidden",
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
  gridList: {
    // width: 1000,
    height: "auto",
  },
  icon: {
    color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54)",
  },
});

class EventsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { events: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
    .get("http://localhost:9000/events/")
    .then((response) => {
      this.setState({ events: response.data });
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
     });
  }

  render() {
     const { classes, width } = this.props;

     let columns = width === "xs" || width === "sm" ? 1 : 3;
     return (
       <div className={classes.root}>
         <GridListTile key="Subheader" style={{ height: "auto" }}>
           <ListSubheader component="div">December</ListSubheader>
         </GridListTile>
         <GridList
          cellHeight={330}
          className={classes.gridList}
          cols={columns}
          spacing={8}
         >
          {this.state.events.map((tile) => (
             <GridListTile key={tile.eventImage}>
             <img src={tile.eventImage} alt={tile.title} />
             <GridListTileBar
             title={tile.title}
             subtitle={<span>by: {tile.author}</span>}
              actionIcon={
                <IconButton
                  aria-label={`info about ${tile.title}`}
                  className={classes.icon}
                ></IconButton>
              }
           />
           </GridListTile>
         ))}
      </GridList>
    </div>
  );
 }
}

export default withStyles(useStyles)(EventsList);
```